# Block Comment Then Unhighlight in Vim

Tags: vim, dictionary, highlight, comments

I have a simple map in ~/.vimrc:

```
map ,/ :s:^://:<CR>
```

However, it leaves an ugly highlight after the search that I remedy with a quick "/fjkljksdk"

Here's my non-working attempt at unhighlighting immediately after the search and replace:

```
map ,/ :s:^://:<CR>|:nohl
```

Thanks for the help -- Mitchell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
map ,/ :s:^://:<BAR>:nohl<CR>
```

Or

```
map ,/ :s:^://:<CR>:nohl<CR>
```

Or

```
map ,/ :call setline('.', substitute(getline('.'), '^', '//', ''))<CR>
```

Comment: The highlight is still there.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is adding `set nohlsearch` to your `~/.vimrc` and forget about that issue in all your searches.

Comment: Yeah, but I do prefer highlighting when I'm actually searching for something.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your goal without using `:s`:

```
nnoremap ,/ I//<Esc>
```

to add `//` right before the first printable character on the current line or:

```
nnoremap ,/ 0i//<Esc>
```

to add `//` at the real beginning of the current line (column 1).